# Spring Integration with Cobertura

Tags: spring-integration, cobertura

I am using spring integration in my application. I have written Junit test cases and initializing spring xml file using spring test framework. I am trying to setup Cobertura but it is not working properly. I am generating report via maven plugin. Just wanted to check if I am using the right tool for code coverage. If not, what else is the good option with spring integration. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Not working properly" will not help anyone understand your problem.

I can't speak to cobertura, but for Spring Integration itself, we use JaCoCo for code coverage [from the gradle build](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/build.gradle#L210). It produces html reports in the build directory and the output file is used by Sonar too.

I use [eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/) in eclipse.